# NameError: uninitialized constant after checking name with .classify

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table that is part of a mountable blog engine in Rails. That table is called `lines_articles`.

```
def change

create_table "lines_articles", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "sub_title"
  t.text     "content"
  t.boolean  "published",        default: false
  t.datetime "published_at"
  t.string   "hero_image"
  t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
  t.string   "slug"
  t.string   "gplus_url"
  t.boolean  "featured",         default: false
  t.string   "document"
  t.string   "short_hero_image"
end
```

I want to show all contents in that table in my rails console, so I ran a .classify to make sure I didn't screw up the plural variable, and the output was:

```
 2.2.1 :015 > "lines_articles".classify
   => "LinesArticle"
```

So now the console confirmed the naming convention, but when I run a simple `LinesArticle.all`, I get an error: `NameError: uninitialized constant LinesArticle`.

How can the console classify a table name and throw a NameError when querying the table with that name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a model class in the `app/models/lines_article.rb` directory.

If you're on Rails 5, it should look something like this:

```
class LinesArticle < ApplicationRecord
end
```

If you're on Rails 4, it should look something like this:

```
class LinesArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Then re-open rails console and try again.

Comment: This works, and I'll mark accepted. Note if anyone else sees this that the model needs an underscore between the words to work.

Comment: @darkginger Yes, I'd like to clarify that the model *file name* requires underscores, as in `app/models/lines_article.rb`.